# Java Version migration and compitibity with JDK version

Tags: java-7, corba

I am planning to upgrade JDk version from 1.6(Java6) to 1.7 (Java 7)for our CORBA Services. Can someone suggest if there would be any compatibility issue with latest java version or any known limitations using old CORBA applications with new java versions? Thanks.

Comment: Which Corba library are you using? Everything depends only on question if Corba library you're using is compatible with Java 7.
If it's not, maybe you can use newer version of the same library.